# I want to select all texts (including node names) under a node

Tags: xslt, xpath

I currently have a xml file like this:

```
<aaa>
    <b>I am a <i>boy</i></b>.
</aaa>
```

How can I get the exact string as: `<b>I am a <i>boy</i></b>.`? Thanks.

Comment: do you have to use xslt? how about xml parser + xpath?

Comment: Please do not put tags (like "[xslt]") into the title line. That's what the tags are for.

Comment: Good Question (+1). See my answer for an explanation and a complete, but short and easy solution. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to tell XSLT that you want to copy elements through as well. That can be done with an additional rule. Note that I use custom select clauses on my apply-templates elements to select attributes as well as all node-type objects. Also note that the rule for aaa takes precedence, and does *not* copy the aaa element itself to the output.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="aaa">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> <aaa> 
>     <b>I am a <i>boy</i></b>. 
> </aaa>
> ```
>
> How can I get the exact string as:
>   `<b>I am a <i>boy</i></b>`.?

**The easiest/shortest way to do this in your case is to output the result of the following XPath expression**:

**`/*/node()`**

**This means**: "*Select all nodes that are children of the top element*."

Of course, there are some white-space-only text nodes that we don't want selected, but XSLT can take care of this, so the XPath expression is just as simple as shown above.

**Now, to get the result with an XSLT transformation, we use the following**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
   <xsl:copy-of select="/*/node()"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document, the wanted result is produced**:

```
<b>I am a <i>boy</i></b>.
```

**Do note**:

1. The use of the `<xsl:copy-of>` xslt instruction (not `<xsl:value-of>`), which copies *nodes*, not string values.
2. The use of the `<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>` XSLT instruction, directing the XSLT processor to ignore any white-space-only text node in the XML document.

Comment: Which goes to show: XSLT can do anything XPath can do. :-) Note that you lose recursive tweakability with this approach.

Comment: It's missing the ".".  The xpath should be something like: `<xsl:copy-of select="/*/node()[not(normalize-space()='')]"/>`, which will serialize to output that is not well-formed, but is the string that was asked for.

Comment: @Mads-Hansen: Thanks, I hadn't noticed the "." -- thought it was a punctuation mark ending the sentence in the question.

I updated my answer accordingly.